# git config for proxy issue

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-bash, git-config

so I'm trying to connect my visual studio 2017 with azure DevOps. I need to set the proxy so when I run the command 
`git config --global HTTP.proxy HTTP://WindowsLogin:PASSWORD@10.43.0.29:8080` 
and set my password and windows login to my PW and user name, it gives me an error
 `[1] 2656 bash: @10.43.0.29:8080: command not found` . what is the error here? by the way my teammate on the same proxy everything worked fine with her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to quote the parameter:

```
git config --global http.proxy 'http://WindowsLogin:PASSWORD@10.43.0.29:8080'
```

I suspect you PASSWORD is ended with an ampersand `&` which is a very special symbol for bash. It means "run the command in background" so bash split your command in two (`git config --global http.proxy 'http://WindowsLogin:PASSWORD` and `@10.43.0.29:8080`), ran the first in the background, tried to run the second and failed.

`[1] 2656` means that bash started job number 1, process id 2656. Could be killed with `kill %1` or `kill 2656`.

Comment: Hey, so I did what you told me and the command didn't give me an error .then I tried to connect to one of the repositories in the DevOps it gives me "installation" as an error message. what is that?

Comment: Hard to say. Perhaps worth a separate question with copy/paste from the terminal.